# Implementing visitor pattern on aggregate objects

Tags: php, aggregate, children, visitor-pattern

I'm struggling with applying the visitor pattern on some objects that have scalar members and at the same time aggregate members (collections).

These are the objects that I have:

```
Artist
 - id
 - name
 - .. more scalar values ..
 - worksOfArt <-- this is a collection as WorkOfArt instances


WorkOfArt
 - id
 - name
 - .. more scalar values ..
 - artists <-- this is a collection of Artist instances
```

As you can see, the structure will also be recursive, but that's of later concern to me. ;-)

My question is: what is the best way to implement the visitor pattern, that allows me visit the objects and also only their visitable children (the collections).

I thought creating an interface like this:

```
VisitableAggregateInterface
{
    public function getVisitableChildren(); // this would return only visitable children
}
```

And then let both Artist and WorkOfArt extend an abstract class like this:

```
VisitableAggregateAbstract implements VisitableAggregateInterface
{
    public function accept( Visitor $visitor )
    {
        $visitor->visit( $this );
        foreach( $this->getVisitableChildren() as $visitableChild )
        {
           $visitableChild->accept( $visitor );
        }
    }

    /*
        VisitableAggregateInterface::getVisitableChildren()
        will be implemented by Artist and WorkOfArt and will only
        return visitable children (like collections), and not scalar values.
    */
}
```

The goal is ultimately to end up with a concrete Visitor that will write out an XML file similar to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<artgallery>
    <artists>
        <artist>
            <id>1</id>
            <name></name>
            <worksOfArt>
                <workOfArt refid="11"/>
                <workOfArt refid="12"/>
            </worksOfArt>
        <artist>
    <artists>
    <worksOfArt>
        <workOfArt>
            <id>11</id>
            <artists>
                <artist refid="1"/>
            </artists>
            <name></name>
            <info><![CDATA[some info]]></info>
        </workOfArt>
        <workOfArt>
            <id>12</id>
            <artists>
                <artist refid="1"/>
            </artists>
            <name></name>
            <info><![CDATA[some info]]></info>
        </workOfArt>
    </worksOfArt>
</artgallery>
```

Please advice: Am I going in the right direction here? Because the `getVisitableChildren()` interface feels a bit quirky to me. Should I perhaps maybe even ditch the visitor pattern altogether and take a different approach?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't actually state what the relation between artist and artwork is. If, as I suspect, both mean the Artist made the WorkOfArt, then you don't have a recursive data structure, so you don't need a visitor pattern.

I would simply "brute force" it. Something like this (untested)

```
echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>
<artgallery>
    <artists>\n";
Foreach (Artists as Artist) {
   echo "        <artist>
            <id>1</id>
            <name></name>
            <worksOfArt>\n";
   ForEach (Artist.worksOfArt as Work) {
      $refid = ????;
      echo "<workOfArt refid=\"$refid"/>\n";
   }
   echo "        </worksOfArt>
        </artist>\n";
}
echo " </artists>
    <worksOfArt>";
Foreach (WorkOfArt as work) {
   ForEach (work.Artists as Artist) {

   }
}
```

Then just put the rest of echo statements into the above

BTW - you have a typo in the question. The close of  and  need /s added.

Comment: You convinced me to leave the visitor pattern behind. I wasn't aware that the visitor pattern is typically meant for recursive data. I decided to take the approach you suggest, although a bit more flexible, since I need to output partial fragments also. But you couldn't have known that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen `Visitor` implemented using a 'traverser' class that has specific knowledge of the types to be visited.  In this case it would 'know' to visit `WorksOfArt` in `Artists` but not `Artists` in `WorksOfArt`.  You can define other traversers for other behaviour.

Dan

Here's some pseudo-code I've dug out... (vb actually, but don't tell anyone :)):

Visitable:

```
Public Interface IVisitable
    Sub accept(ByVal visitor As IVisitor)
End Interface
```

Visitor:

```
Public Interface IVisitor
    Sub visit(ByVal visitable As IVisitable)
End Interface
```

Traverser:

```
Public Class PaymentListExportTraverser
    Private payments As PaymentList
    Private visitor As IVisitor

    Public Sub New(ByVal paymentList As PaymentList, ByVal exportVisitor As IVisitor)
        payments = paymentList
        visitor = exportVisitor
    End Sub

    Public Sub traverse()
        For Each p As Payment In payments
            p.accept(visitor)
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Dan, thanks for your answer. Since I was kind of on the fence about using the visitor pattern already, Ian convinced me to leave it behind. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Hmm.  Ok.  Be aware though that Visitor is not specific to recursive structures.